# CAAnimation repeatable animation queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation

Is there is any way to create repeatable animation queue using CAAnimation? For example: I have a ball which should make one clockwise rotation (2 * PI) and two counterclockwise rotations (4*PI) and these animations should repeated forever.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a `UIView` keyframe animation (using `animateKeyframesWithDuration`) set to repeat, or create a `CAAnimationGroup` composed of your separate animation steps timed to run one right after the other, and set up the entire animation group to repeat.

Getting rotations of a full circle or more is a little tricky however. Normally a rotation of 2*PI doesn't do anything because the end result is that the layer winds up at the same angle.

The secret is to use a `CAValueFunction` to specify a rotation around the Z axis (assuming that's what you want.)

I have a project called [**KeyframeViewAnimations**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/KeyframeViewAnimations) that illustrates both creating keyframe animations and using CAValueFunction to do rotations of > 2PI (although it's two separate animations in my sample project.)

Comment: The rotation of a layer isn't actually limited to one full circle, so if you rotate by 2*PI, it's not the same angle as 0.

Other than that, I agree, a keyframe animation would be really helpful.